# fadeIn and slide chaining on div

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to show a `<div>` called settings when I click a button. It should fade in and then slide to the right. It fades in on the left side of the screen.

I have so far:

**The HTML**

```
<div id="settings" ng-show="settings">

</div>
```

and the link to call the `showSettings() function`:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="showSettings()"><i class="icon setting"></i></a>
```

**The CSS**

```
#settings {
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:400px;
}
```

**The Controller**

```
$scope.showSettings = function(){
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.settings = true;
    }, 250);     
}
```

So I have it fading in but how do I now make it slide to the right by say `200px`?

Also, I would like to be able to click anywhere other than the `<div>` itself to reverse the process.

Comment: @HunterTurner: tag  removed, so not an issue any more :)

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

add `ng-class="{slide:slideFlag}"`

in controller

```
$scope.showSettings = function () {
$timeout(function () {
  $scope.settings = true;
  $timeout(function () {
    $scope.slideFlag = true;  
  }, 250);

}, 250);
```

and in css:

```
.slide{
    transition: all 0.5s;
    margin-left:200px;
}
```

here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/q5cqh9qj/

also, the reason for using two `timeouts` is, you can't run `transition` while you are changing `display` property (settings = true;)

Comment: cheers for this - how would you recommend reversing the process. Add some kind of click handler to the whole of the right hand side of the page?

Comment: You could add a click handler to the document

Comment: Do I need to add another css rule to get the div to slide back again?

Comment: No, In settings CSS, set margin-left as 0, but then in slide CSS put an important along the margin left ( otherwise Id would override class selector)

Comment: but the settings css has a `left:0`

Comment: Yeah that is different from margin-left

Comment: it's just when I add `margin-left` it stops sliding altogether

Comment: Did you add !important to the slide CSS margin-left

Comment: Thanks - that's fixed that. It's going back now but just not sliding. It's instant.

Comment: For sliding back you can use the same timeout kind of thing...don't set settings and slide Flag false at the same time

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I'm doing - I've added a hideSettings function - to be honest only the slide animation works for the showSettings code you added, not the fadeIn

Comment: Can you create a new fiddle or update the fiddle? I set a width and height explicitly I am not sure whether this caused it to not fade in

Comment: why does the `.slide` css have a transition time as well as a timeout in Angular?

Comment: Because it cannot be set true at the same time as scope.settings, otherwise the animation won't work

Comment: I'll have a mess around later on with it - thanks for your help!